# Get Last Element in C# using XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have a XML feed loaded in an XElement.

The structure is

```
<root>
<post></post>
<post></post>
<post></post>
<post></post>
.
.
.
.
<post></post>
</root>
```

I want to directly get the value of the Last post. How I do that using XElement in C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or try this to get XElement:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml");          
XElement root = doc.Root;
Console.WriteLine(root.Elements("post").Last());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LastNode` property on root element:

```
XElement root = doc.Root;
XElement lastPost = (XElement)root.LastNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var lastPost = doc.Descendants("post").Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rootElement.Descendants().Last()
```

If you aren't sure there'll be any, you could also use LastOrDefault(). If there might be other elements besides  within the , there's an overload of Descendants that will let you find just the posts you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XDocument doc= XDocument.Load("path to xml");
var last=doc.Root.LastNode;
```