# c# XML parsing - last node (linq)

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

This is my XML:

```
   <start>
  <Move id = "1">
    <X1>234</X1>
    <Y1>234</Y1>
    <Z1>234</Z1>
  </Move>
  <Move id = "2">
    <X1>546</X1>
    <Y1>56</Y1>
    <Z1>345</Z1>
  </Move>
<start>
```

Now this is the code i am using to ceate it:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument( new XElement( "start", 
 new XElement( "Move", new XAttribute("id", ""),
 new XElement( "X1", x1 ), 
  new XElement( "Y1", y1), 
 new XElement( "Z1", z1 ))));
```

Every time i'll start my program i will append node  to this XML file and for that i need to retrieve last node which will give me node ID.

So in short ... "How do i access last node?"

I have tried but no success.

Could someone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: Check this link : [StackOverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884804/get-last-element-in-c-sharp-using-xelement

Comment: `int lastId = (int)doc.Descendants("Move").Last().Attribute("id")`

Comment: Ahh and i was googling for an hour with wrong keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the xml:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

and then

```
int id = (int?)xdoc
    .Elements("start")
    .Elements("Move")
    .Attributes("id")
    .LastOrDefault() ?? 0;
```

`id` will be 0 if there are no `Move` elements, or with the last `id` otherwise.

Note that if you prefer,

```
int? id = (int?)xdoc
    .Elements("start")
    .Elements("Move")
    .Attributes("id")
    .LastOrDefault();
```

Now `id` will be `null` if there are no `Move` elements, or with the last `id` otherwise.