# How to get the last XElement of particular type C#, XML, LINQtoXML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I've come across different ways of getting the last element (there are several `<hour>` elements and two other but only the last `<hour>` element is the target needed)  on the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884804/get-last-element-in-c-sharp-using-xelement), e.g.:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Source.xml");          
XElement lastHour = doc.Root.Elements("hour").Last();
```

It doesn't work for me. When I put down 'dot' after `Elements("hour")`, trying to call `Last()` method, SharpDevelop doesn't see it. What's wrong with it?

The whole block of code is:

```
if (hour == hisDoc.Root.Elements("hour").Last) {
     if ((hisDoc.Element("scanerHIS").Element("constants") != null) && (fcsDay.XPathSelectElement("constants") == null)) {
     fcsDay.Add(new XElement("constants",
          new XAttribute("P001", hisDoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("constants").Attribute("P001").Value),
          new XAttribute("Q001", hisDoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("constants").Attribute("Q001").Value),
          new XAttribute("N2", hisDoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("constants").Attribute("N2").Value),
          new XAttribute("CO2", hisDoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("constants").Attribute("CO2").Value)));
     }
}
fcsDoc.Save(FCSfileName);
```

Comment: you have linq in your usings right?

Comment: @Isparia, `System.Xml.Linq`, you're right.

Comment: try using `using System.Linq;` in addition, im not sure if it will help. But it might.

Comment: @Isparia, I've just tried: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' and 'groups of methods'. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Use Descendants instead of Elements.

Comment: @jdweng, the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thanks to everyone who helped.

I need to write using `System.Linq`, because System.Xml.Linq doesn't contain `Last()` method.

The answer is:

```
if (hour == hisDoc.Root.Descendants("hour").Last())
```

Comment: You do not need Root when using Descendants.